# Tracking visits to my Tumblr from mobile devices (iPhone)

Tags: google-analytics, tumblr

I've been using the instructions [here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/google_analytics) to track visits to my Tumblr with Google Analytics for the last several months, but just realized today that the JavaScript doesn't run at all on mobile devices.

Is there any way to make this work? The majority of traffic to our site probably comes from mobile devices, so we'd really like to track this.

Answer (score 2):

Not all mobile devices can handle JavaScript so the Google Analytics code won't work on every mobile device. Google covers how to handle this with server side code as [outlined here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/overview.html):

> **Activity on websites specially tailored for low-end mobile devices**
>
> All the same data that you've come to expect from your Google
>   Analytics reports is now available for mobile websites. Simply paste
>   our [server-side code snippets](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/mobileWebsites.html) (available for PHP, JSP, ASP.NET, and
>   Perl) on each page you wish to track. Google Analytics then creates a
>   profile for your mobile website where you can view the same kind of
>   information that's in standard Analytics reports including visitor
>   information and traffic sources. You'll be able to track users
>   visiting your mobile website from both high-end "smartphones" and WAP
>   devices.
>
> For more information on tracking hits to mobile sites, see the
>   [server-side developer's guide](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/mobileWebsites.html).

Comment: Thanks, John. To clarify, I care specifically about the iPhone. I know JavaScript works in Mobile Safari, but Tumblr seems to strip out the Javascript tags in the mobile template.

Comment: Can you edit the mobile template? If so you should be able to place the code into your custom HTML which *should* solve this problem. I'm not a tumblr user so I'm not sure exactly how that works.